# CapyBara & Cucumber not resetting cookies / sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, capybara

Here's what I'm doing in my tests.

1. User enters their shop name
2. User gives credentials
3. User adds a record to DB

First scenario, everything runs smooth. Second scenario, the problem is that we skip the OAuth credentials page so the test is failing.

How do I avoid this? (I'm new to testing)

step file:

```
    Before do
      @shop = FactoryGirl.build(:shop)
    end


    Given /^I am a logged in user$/ do
        visit root_path
        fill_in :shop, :with => "jims-spears"
        click_button 'Install'
        expect(page).to have_content('Log in to manage')
        fill_in :login, :with => 'jackson@example.com'
        fill_in :password, :with => "12345"
        click_button 'Log in'
        expect(page).to have_content("We'll automatically")
    end



    Given /^the customer is a (.+) athlete$/ do |type|
      athlete_type = (type + "_athlete").to_sym
      @customer = create(athlete_type, :shop => @shop)
    end
```

feature file:

```
Feature: User adds a customer manually

  Background:
    Given I am a logged in user


  Scenario: User adds a customer who is a swimming athlete
    Given the customer is a swimming athlete
    When I add the customer
    Then I should see that the customer is an athlete

  Scenario: User adds a customer who is a rowing athlete
    Given the customer is a rowing athlete
    When I add the customer
    Then I should see that the customer is an athlete
```

I tried adding an a hook in the step file with no luck

```
After do
  @shop.destroy
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the test failing? Is it failing on the login step or creating @customer?

Comment: I think your test is pretty confused -- your scenarios are stating that the user is adding a customer which a X athlete, but then you're stating a Given of the customer being a specific type of athlete -- Givens are usually for things that are to pre-exist in the system setup for the test.  In your cases I would expect   "When I add a swimming athlete"  as a step in the test --  You aren't showing the definition for the "I add a customer"  step though so I may be misreading things.  Also, rather than adding an after step to destroy shop take a look at the database_cleaner gem